# Iterating through all the possible combinations of several lists items

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I have a face model with 12 blendshapes where each blendshape is simply a list of float values between **0** (neutral facial expression) and **1** (maximum activated expression) but I am starting off with only the first 2 blendshapes; i.e. only two lists for now, say smile and skeptic looks.

My intention is to go through all the possible combinations of all the items in these two lists and make a footage (movie clip) of the facial movements, to display how all the possible combinations of blendshape values/weights look like.

So, I wrote the following to facilitate this scenario for only two blendshapes for now, and I save them to file as soon as the application closes:

```
public class BlendShapesVAL : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<float> _weightValues_Preset1_smile   = new List<float>();
    private List<float> _weightValues_Preset2_skeptic = new List<float>();

    public bool _TransitionAnimation = true;
    public float _TransitionAnimationSpeed = 2f;

    public BlendShapesPresetController _BSPC;

    private List<float> _weightsList = new List<float>();

    public List<bool> _ActivationsList = new List<bool>();
    public List<string> _PresetsNamesList = new List<string>();


    private void Awake()
    {        
        _weightsList.Clear();
        _ActivationsList.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _PresetsNamesList.Count; ++i)
        {
            _ActivationsList.Add(false);
            _weightsList.Add(0);
        }
     }


    private void Start()
    {
        if (_BSPC != null)
        {
            // . . .
        }
        else
        {
            _BSPC = GetComponent<BlendShapesPresetController>();
        }

        StartCoroutine("Interpolate");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Writes (i.e. saves) blendshape values to file when the application quits.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        SaveBlendShapesValues(_weightValues_Preset1_smile);
        SaveBlendShapesValues(_weightValues_Preset2_skeptic);

        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Goes thorugh all the possible combinations of blendshape weights.
    /// For now, only the first two though!
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private IEnumerator Interpolate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            float weightValuesmile = (float)i / 100.0f;
            _BSPC.SetWeight("Preset1_smile", weightValuesmile);
            _weightValues_Preset1_smile.Add(weightValuesmile);

            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                float weightValueSkeptic = (float)j / 100.0f;
                _BSPC.SetWeight("Preset2_skeptic", weightValueSkeptic);
                _weightValues_Preset2_skeptic.Add(weightValueSkeptic);
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Writes (i.e. saves) blendshape values to file.
    /// <param name="blendShapesValuesFilePath">
    /// The path to the file that will store the list of float values;
    /// i.e. "Application.dataPath" plus the name of the CSV file.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="values">
    /// The float values that are the blendshape weights.
    /// </param>
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private static void SaveBlendShapesValues(List<float> values)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>
        {
            /// Add a header row for the labels.
            "TimeStamp,Preset1_smile,Preset2_skeptic"
        };

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            /// Iterate through all the elements.
            lines.Add(DateTime.Now + "," + value);
        }

        /// Load the old counter.
        int counter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_counter_", 0);

        /// Concatenate the file name constituents and combine it with the application data path.
        string fileName = string.Format("BlendShapesValues_{0}.csv", counter.ToString() );
        string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, fileName);

        try
        {            
            File.WriteAllLines(tempPath, lines.ToArray() );
            Debug.Log("Saved blendshape weight values to: " + tempPath);

            /// Increment the counter.
            counter++;

            /// Save the current counter.
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_counter_", counter);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to save to PlayerPrefs: " + tempPath);
            Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
        }        
    }
}
```

In the Unity Editor, the blendshapes are displayed with values from 0 to 100, hence my conversion in the code, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

The first file has **101** values (0...100 plus a top row for column labels) a snippet can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

The second file has **10201** values. My **first question** is whether this method of saving the iterated values to file after the app stops is a good solution, given the large growth in the values as I add more lists (i.e. blendshapes)?

My **second question** is how I can slow down the iterations, because (in the first screenshot) the smile values start counting up from 0 to 100 and I can see them (the face moves slowly in a visible manner) but as that is happening, I notice that the second list (skeptic) apparently jumps to 100 immediately, so it is done so quickly that it cannot be recorded by the Win screen recorder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was not sure if this could be a comment or an answer so let me know if i am missing something.

For your first question if you are okay with those saved files being non-readable by humans i would suggest using `BinaryReader`. Because size of saved files would be smaller and when you want to read them back to make your clip it will read it faster. Also, considering you want to have 12 blend shapes and their combination this file can be huge.

For your second question iteration jumps to 100 because you only yield when the inner loop is completed. Therefore, in each frame 100 combinations of skeptical for 1 smile are added to the list. I would recommend using multi threading or Unity job system for such a task because it can be computationally costly with 12 blendshapes and all the combinations.

Let me know if i can help further. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Ali. I put the `yield` statement in the inner loop, so now it does exactly what I need, hence marking your answer as right! I prefer the files to be human-readable, at least for now, so perhaps I should use `StreamWriter `?

Comment: I am not sure about `StreamWriter` because now you can write all lines i do not know if `StreamWriter` offers this also usually writing is not a problem but reading is always problematic. I would recommend using `BufferedStream` while reading also if i were you i would structure my csv file in a way that it would not require any `string.split` operations because `split` can be really slow. Good luck!